# Conda Init Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, nvidia-jetson-nano

I installed anaconda but when I ran conda init doesn't work,I'm using ssh to install that on a remote jetson nano ( ARM architecture).

Answer (score 7):

I faced the similar issue while using miniconda. I tried to downgrade miniconda version from 4.10.1 to 4.9.2, and then the problem solved.
Maybe you should install older version of anaconda.

Comment: Ah, perfect. For any future readers, this did work for me as well on both of my ubuntu installations.

Comment: Spoke too soon. While it's fixed in (base), my other environments get the same error when pip installing anything.

Comment: Worked for me using Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh. The link to download: https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/